# 'Skimming' for a video

Tags: word-request

To read through a book or some other text is called *skimming*. But all the dictionaries I checked define it as "to *read* superficially"- so **what is the word for casually watching a video** without being an involved, thorough viewer, perhaps skipping forward a little at times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best word for this is probably *skim*.

There are certainly dictionary definitions that would seem to allow for this use, e.g.

> 2 : to read, study, or examine superficially and rapidly

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skim)

> to read or consider something quickly in order to understand the main points, without studying it in detail:

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/skim)

But the more important point is that people appear to use the word this way.  Look at these user comments from various on-line discussion forums:

"Sorry I didn't reply earlier when I first read post but then I only skimmed the video"[<sup>1</sup>](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=33933429)

"i skimmed the video and dont understand how they got to 11k rpm?" [<sup>2</sup>](https://www.ferrarichat.com/forum/threads/chris-harris-drives-the-tuthill-porsche-911k-the-astonishing-350hp-lightweight-machine.682104/)

"I have skimmed the video and will come back later and look at the whole thing in detail." [<sup>3</sup>](https://www.festoolownersgroup.com/general-friendly-chat/history-of-tools-vid/)

"Then I skimmed the video and selected the part that I am interested in and dragged it to the project window" [<sup>4</sup>](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2550343)

The fact that this specific meaning is not captured by dictionaries is probably because the act of skimming through videos is relatively new.

---

Another option might be *glance over/at/through*.

> If you glance through or at a newspaper, report, or book, you spend a short time looking at it without reading it very carefully.

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/glance)

This phrase probably has a longer history of being used to refer to the act of looking superficially at something, without necessarily reading it.  For instance, you can glance through a stack of photographs.  However, to my mind at least, *glance* does not imply any kind of listening.  So if I were *glancing* at a video, I might be doing it from far away, so that I couldn't hear the sound.

Comment: There was a [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/whatstheword/comments/p9xbad/wtw_for_skimming_through_a_movie/) on this question where the best options were "skimming" or "half-watching". And certainly a lot of other uses of "video skimming" etc online.